# Can't get VSCode debbuging to work with my NodeJs app

Tags: node.js, debugging, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I'm having trying to debug my app on Visual Studio Code. I have the following config on my `package.json`:

```
"scripts": {
    "build": "rimraf dist/ && babel ./ --out-dir dist/ --ignore ./node_modules,./.babelrc,./package.json,./npm-debug.log --copy-files",
    "start": "npm run build && node --inspect=12345 dist/app.js"
}
```

Im using ES6 on my Node app, that's why it is kinda messy my `build` config.

When I run `npm start` everything works fine, I can use my app.

Now to try to debug it, I have set the following `launch` configurations:

```
"configurations": [
    {
        "type": "node",
        "name": "Attach to Remote",
        "request": "attach",
        "port": 12345
    },
    {
        "type": "node",
        "request": "launch",
        "name": "Launch Program",
        "program": "${workspaceFolder}\\dist\\app.js"
    }
]
```

Both of them ""work"": VS Code switch to "debug mode" but I can't hit any breakpoints. They all get grayed out:

[image]

I have tried to fix using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50804332/vs-code-unverified-breakpoints) answer, but couldn't get it to work...

Any help?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out I was just missing the `--source-maps` from my `babel-cli` command... -.-
After adding it, VSCode is able to find the breakpoints.
So basically the solution was:

Add `--source-maps` to my build command:

```
"scripts": {
    "build": "rimraf dist/ && babel ./ --out-dir dist/ --ignore ./node_modules,./.babelrc,./package.json,./npm-debug.log --copy-files --source-maps",
    "start": "npm run build && node --inspect=12345 dist/app.js"
 }
```

And I configured a `launch` as follows:

```
"configurations": [
    {
        "type": "node",
        "request": "launch",
        "name": "Launch Program",
        "program": "${workspaceFolder}\\dist\\app.js",
        "preLaunchTask": "npm: build"
    }
]
```

Hope it helps someone!

Answer (score 0):

I am using VS Code v 1.28.2 and I'm able to debug both ways.

1) With the built in debuger ( Menu -> Debug -> Start Debuging)

2) starting the application with `node inspect index.js`. In that case you have to declare breakpoints in your code with the `debugger;` keyword. Then, when in debug-mode and stoped in a breakpoint, you continue execution typing `cont` in the command line.

hope it helps

Comment: Thanks for the answer, gkont. This did work but I was expecting to use breakpoints instead of debugger. I found out a solution! Thanks!